# Making http request to Google API with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api

I'm trying to make a request to the Google Analytics API. I'm using Passport.js to authorize the user and [this library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to make requests.

I get a nice repsonse from Google but my problem is that the request keeps on going until it times out even after I've received the repsonse. The request keeps un running until I get a time out.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + access_token,  function (error, response, body) {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      console.log(repsonse);
    }
});
```

Comment: in what context are you calling this from?

Comment: @materik not following, what do you mean by context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not just returning something from the HTTP GET call you're doing. That's why it times out.

You need to send back a HTTP 200 if error does not eval to true, e.g.:

```
res.send();
```